# Move std::array to an other std::array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to move an array to an other array (for initialize my datas structure).

My code:

```cpp
void MonitorModule::setParameters(const std::array<std::string, IMonitorModule::MAX_CONTENT> &parameters) const {
    this->_parameters = parameters;
}

// Inside the structure "MonitorModule" as private
std::array<std::string, IMonitorModule::MAX_CONTENT> _parameters;
```

This is returning the following error:

> error: no viable overloaded '='

How can I do this move of two std::array ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`setParameters()` is qualified as `const`, which means it can only be called on a `const MonitorModule` object and thus  its `_parameters` member cannot be modified. That is why the compiler cannot find a suitable `operator=` to assign another array to `_parameters`.

You need to drop the `const` qualifier from the declaration of `setParameters()`.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `const` after method definition prevents modifying its members, so you should remove it or make `_parameters` mutable.

Answer (score 2):

`MonitorModule::setParameters` is qualified `const`, meaning that it can't change object members.

Simply remove the `const` qualification.